# Is there a way to use iOS speech recognition in offline mode?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, apple-speech

I want to know if there's a way to use iOS speech recognition in offline mode. According to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) I didn't see anything about it.

Comment: You can dictate into a textField and textView using the mic button on the software keyboard. That works in offline mode. Don't think interpret speech commands though.

Comment: @Magnas are you *pretty* sure that the mic button should be enabled even when offline mode? I tested on four different iPhones and it was disabled...

Comment: Same for me @AhmadF, mic button is not available in my app when offline mode is on (http://imgur.com/GHZ9I6x).

Comment: Hmmm it's on by default in mine. I'll go check more closely.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am afraid that there is *no way* to do it *(however, please make sure to check the update at the end of the answer)*.

As mentioned at the [Speech Framework Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech):

> **Best Practices for a Great User Experience:**
>
> *Be prepared to handle the failures that can be caused by reaching speech recognition limits.*
>   Because speech recognition **is a network-based service**, limits are
>   enforced so that the service can remain freely available to all apps.

---

As an end user perspective, trying to get *Siri's* help without connecting to a network should displays a screen similar to:

[image]

Also, When trying to send a massage -for example-, you'll notice that the mike button should be disabled if the device is unconnected to a network.

[image]

Natively, the iOS itself won't able this feature until checking network connection, I assume that would be the same for the third-party developer when using the Speech Framework.

---

### **UPDATE:**

After watching [Speech Recognition API Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/) (especially, the part 03:00 - 03:25) , I came up with:

Speech Recognition API ***usually*** requires an internet connection, but there are some of new devices do support this feature all the time; You might want to check whether the given language is available or not.

Adapted from [SFSpeech​Recognizer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer):

> Note that a supported speech recognizer is not the same as an
>   available speech recognizer; for example, the recognizers *for some
>   locales may require an Internet connection*. You can use the
>   `supported​Locales()` method to get a list of supported locales and the
>   `is​Available` property to find out if the recognizer for a specific
>   locale is available.

**Further Reading:**

These topics might be related:

- [Which iOS devices support​ offline speech recognition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277435/which-ios-devices-support-offline-speech-recognition)
- [How to Enable Offline Dictation on Your iPhone?](http://iphone-tricks.com/tutorial/1656-offline-dictation-on-iphone-6s-how-to-enable)
- [Will Siri ever work offline?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/will-siri-ever-work-offline.1884521/)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer @AhmadF ! Unfortunately, I conclude the same before asking. :/

Is it because the Speech Framework is new born since iOS 10 and it will be improved in future perhaps ? Let's wait lel...

Comment: @DanylS I hope so... however, it does support offline mode, but I think that applied for few cases, check my updated answer :)

Comment: I just took a look on it, thanks @ AhmadF, it's very useful for me. 
Could you tell me more details about which iPhone models is supported ?

Comment: @DanylS Honestly, I have no idea for now :D, I'll update my answer once I got information about it; The thing is you should check if the device supported locales before checking if there is an internet connection.

Comment: @AhmadF Thank you for this helpful summery. It worked on iPhone 6s for english. Not sure about others. (Maybe iPhone 6s and later supported.)

Comment: @ZaidPathan glad to help, so far there is no updates regarding to this, However, I could mention you in a comment if case of updating it :)

Comment: Worked offline on iPhone 6s. Didn't work on iPhone 6.

Comment: @ZaidPathan it seems that it is the case that I mentioned in the "UPDATE"!

Answer (score 21):

Offline transcription will be available starting in iOS 13. You enable it with [`requiresOnDeviceRecognition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/3152603-requiresondevicerecognition).

### Example code (Swift 5):

```
// Create and configure the speech recognition request.
recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else { fatalError("Unable to create a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object") }
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

// Keep speech recognition data on device
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
}
```