# Apple - On which Apple devices 'Dictation' is available even in Offline Mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, siri

You can see using plane mode, the mic to use 'Dictation' is unavailable.

[image]

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42900928/6155942) and to the screenshot below from my iOS app : Is there is anyone know which kind of Apple devices is allowable to use 'Dictation' in Offline Mode ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the update in the post you linked: you can use `supportedLocales()` to get the list of supported locales and also `is​Available` for the current locale to see if it's available.

The user has to turn on dictation `System Preferences -> General -> Keyboard`. It's available in English but not for e.g Swedish.

Comment: As you can see my device is in english, my keyboard too and I have also mic disabled with Offline Mode. What does that mean by: 'use supportedLocales()' ?

Comment: There is a method of [SFSpeechrecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer) to get the list of supported locales. You have to check if it's available as well since some require internet access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't need know about 'require internet access.' I want to know, according to my previous question, which devices (iPhone, iPad and so on) is available to use 'Dictation' keyboard features in Offline Mode.